# Read file from different server Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv, amazon-s3

If I try to read a file from the different server, for eg amazon s3 bucket. In app engine its try to locate files in the war directory of the same application.

File am trying to access
URL : http://files.com/report.csv

The above url is processed something like

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /base/data/home/apps/app-Id/modue-Id:1.383112761745940476/http:/files.com/report.csv.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

Well its hard to pinpiont without seeing the code but you seem to have 2 issues:

1) you are looking for http:/files.com/report.csv you are missing a second "/" after http:/

2) you are addressing a "relative" url, therefore GAE is looking for a file within the file system. Which is not what you want.

**what you need to do:** Use the [URL Fetch service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) and get the file as as stream and then process it. The examples on the link should help but here's the gist:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/atom.xml");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // ...
    }
    reader.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a file as if this file is on your own server. You need to use [URL Fetch API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to read the file.